# find the correct coordinates for every object's pixels appearring in first image in the other images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

I have images of object took it from different sides, i want to find out the correct position for every object's pixel appearing in image 1, in the other images

[image: image1]

[image: image1]

[image: image1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thank you! what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: This forum is for correcting code. It is not a code writing service. Please make an attempt and show us your code. Hint: You will need a full camera model for each image. See for example https://learnopencv.com/camera-calibration-using-opencv/

Comment: i'm not looking for code, i'm looking for steps to solve the problem or any method already did the solution

Comment: Render your image without shading and a unique color per texture coordinate. Then same color in first image will be found in second image if the object point is visible.

Comment: i've to work with this dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using features matching + homography from OpenCV, for more details : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html